# How to solve a maze with a Queue?

Tags: java

I'm very confused on how I would solve a maze using a queue. I've provided some javadocs and some psuedo code that my professor has given us. Help if possibble. I've looked on other topics but I could not understand there's hopefully someone can help me with my solve method. thanks

```
public class QueueMazeSolver implements MazeSolver {

private MazeGUI gui;

public static class Cell {

    private int r;
    private int c;

    public Cell(int row, int col){

        r = row;
        c = col;

    }

}


public QueueMazeSolver(){

    gui = new MazeGUI( this );

}

/**
 * This method is called when the start button is
 * clicked in the MazeGUI.  This method should solve the maze.
 * This method may call MazeGUI.drawMaze(...) whenever the
 * GUI display should be updated (after each step of the solution).
 * 
 * The maze is provided as the first parameter.  It is a 2D array containing
 * characters that represent the spaces in the maze.  The following 
 * characters will be found in the array:
 *    '#' - This represents a wall.
 *    ' ' - This represents an open space (corridor)
 *    
 * When calling MazeGUI.drawMaze(...) to update the display, the GUI
 * will recognize the '#' and ' ' characters as well as the following:
 *    '@' - Means the cell is a space that has been explored
 *    '%' - Means that the cell is part of the best path to the goal.
 * 
 * @param maze the maze (see above).
 * @param startR the row of the start cell.
 * @param startC the column of the start cell.
 * @param endR the row of the end (goal) cell.
 * @param endC the column of the end (goal) cell.
 */
@Override
public void solve(char[][] maze, int startR, int startC, int endR, int endC) {

    maze[startR][startC] = '@';

    ArrayQueue<Cell> agenda = new ArrayQueue<Cell>();

    Cell temp = new Cell(startR, startC);

    agenda.offer(temp);

            // while agenda is not empty and red not found
    while(!agenda.isEmpty() && maze[endR][endC] != '@' ){

        Cell current = agenda.poll(); //remove front square from queue

        /*
        if front square is red
            found it
        else 
            mark amaze all unexplored neighbors of front
            square and add them to the square
        */

        if(current == new Cell(endR, endC) ){
            break;
        }
        else{

            =
            }
        }

        /** Notes
        maze[r][c] = '@' //marking cell seen

        up = r-1, c
        down = r+1, c
        left = r, c-1
        right = r, c+1
        */


    }

    if (!agenda.isEmpty())
            gui.setStatusText("Maze is solvable");
    else
        gui.setStatusText("Maze is unsolvable");



    gui.drawMaze(maze);
    try {Thread.sleep(150);}
    catch (InterruptedException e){
        System.err.println("Thread interrupted");
    }       
 }

public static void main(String[] args){

    QueueMazeSolver solver = new QueueMazeSolver();

   }

     }
```

Comment: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/2/7/maze-generation-algorithm-recap is a very helpful site for this type of thing. To solve also look at depth first searching with back tracking.

Answer (score 2):

it seems you are trying to get possible paths to move in a maze and reach `red` cell ,  which has walls (can't cross) or open space .

Basically this code is applying a [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first%5fsearch) .
we remove a cell from `queue` and if the surrounding cells `[at distance 1 unit]` are not visited , add them to `queue` and visit them .
Pseudocode (from wikipedia) :

```
1  procedure BFS(G,v) is
2      create a queue Q
3      create a vector set V
4      enqueue v onto Q
5      add v to V
6      while Q is not empty loop
7         t ← Q.dequeue()
8         if t is what we are looking for then
9            return t
10        end if
11        for all edges e in G.adjacentEdges(t) loop
12           u ← G.adjacentVertex(t,e)
13           if u is not in V then
14               add u to V
15               enqueue u onto Q
16           end if
17        end loop
18     end loop
19     return none
20 end BFS
```

suppose you are at cell`(i,j)` , therefore t=`(i,j)` and adjacentEdges(t) are `(i+1,j)` , `(i,j+1)` , `(i-1,j)` . `(i,j-1)`
If `(i+1,j)` is not visited before , add it to queue (so , next time you pop from queue , you will get it) else if it is visited (i.e in `V`) then we are done with it . Repeat same for other three cells .

This way you do `O(m*n)` operations and visit each cell exactly once .

Comment: confused on what the vertex is and what does line 5 do?

Comment: for my example what would type would my "t" be?

Comment: line 5 : v(1st cell from where you start) is visited  and   

`t` : cell

Comment: I cant upvote yet, and also im still confused on how to do the for loop

Comment: ok , then just understand node as your cell , adjacent means cells at distance 1 from the current cell . I think you are unaware of graphs , so i would strongly recommend you to read wikipedia article first (in words , if unable to follow up pseudocode) or search over internet for bfs , and watch some animations on how it works . Good luck .

Comment: can you at least show me how I would start it please? starting with the for loop?

Comment: can you check my code now? would it be something like that for one of them?

Comment: sorry , but i don't understand java . You can post it on codereview.stackexchange .